Snmpd services getting crashes due to segmentation fault (segv/11)
We have a ubuntu 20.04 servers. On which snmpd service getting failed in 2 to 3 days. I've upgraded package to 5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu.2.9.In logs, I can see docker error and segmentation fault. Can some one help me to resolve following issue.
